# Get nearest point on polyline when mousemove (gMaps v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline

I have an application that shows tracking data. With the map, and the track, I have a chart that show the speed of each point of the polilyne. When I move over the chart, the same point in the maps is highlighted.

What I need to do is: when I move the pointer over the polyline on the map, also  highlight the point on the chart, for this, I need to get the nearest point from the polyline to the mouse pointer on the map.

I binded the polyline mousemove event, but I can't find any property that helps me.

Comment: Did you try anything for this? include that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the point(latLng) is a property of the [mouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polylineInstance, 'mousemove',function(e){
  console.log(e.latLng)
})
```

To get the clicked segment of the Polyline, iterate over the path of the Polyline, create a temporarily polyline for each segment and use [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#poly)  to check if the click has been on the current segment.

Comment: Yes, but, this property is about the latlng where the pointer is. suppose I have a polyline of 8 km, consisting of 10 points. I need to know the segment of this polyline where the pointer is, what are the points that are before and after that segment.Because these points hava a one on one relation with the points of the chart.

Comment: if the polyline is a scribble that passes several times near where the mouse pointer is, I can not find the latlng closer to that point, I need to know exactly what are the points of the segment where I am positioned with the mouse pointer.